# Is there an API for windows console?

Tags: windows, api, console

So when I use Visual Studio whenever I debug an piece of code, a black window pops up that allows you to see cout and type in input. Is there an API that you could use to create and manipulate that window?

Comment: @Filburt: That's not Windows API, it is .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There certainly is, it is named "Console API".

The documentation for the Windows console features begins with

- [Using the Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-console)

It has quite a number of examples as well as documentation for each of the [Console API Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions)